# Actual landscape OpenGL View on iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es, screen, landscape

I'm porting a C++-based engine from Android to iOS and I have some questions on how landscape mode on iOS devices work.

I can successfully start my device on landscape mode but my framebuffer stays on portrait mode no matter how I rotate it (or force its rotation). For instance, I would expect a 960x640 resolution instead of the default 320x480.

I've been researching about it and I saw some people doing this but explicitly rotating the scene using OpenGL, which means the actual axis were not in landscape mode, which for me is an ugly workaround.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure your OpenGL UIView is attached to a UIViewController and not inserted directly into the UIWindow.  To do that, create a custom view controller:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
@end

@implementation MyViewController
- (void)loadView {
    // Create your EAGL view
    MyEAGLView *eaglView = [[MyEAGLView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
    self.view = eaglView;
    [eaglView release];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
@end
```

Then add it to your app's window via the AppDelegate:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
    MyViewController *viewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
    [self.window setRootViewController:viewController];
    [viewController release];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

self.window is just the app's UIWindow, you may have to change that if you store the window somewhere else.

After that, the UIViewController takes care of rotations and resizing your view when the device is turned and you can override the layoutSubviews method in your MyEAGLView object to handle resizing the OpenGL context.  You may also want to look at Apple's sample code for OpenGL apps since it correctly handles this stuff.

Comment: It works great, but the screen remains black if I set a zero rect like the one in your sample. When I set it to [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] it creates a 320x480 frame buffer and stretches it along the landscape frame of the device, as expected.
If I manually invert the axis of the side to 480x320 it works great, but is there a safer way? Notice that I won't need to perform frame buffer resize at runtime, only when it starts.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a safer way per-se -- this is essentially how Apple's own sample code does it as well.  I'm not sure why a zero rect would cause problems since the view controller should immediately resize it after you call setRootViewController on its controller.  Maybe the zero rect is screwing up the initialization of the OpenGL context.

Comment: I should mention, check your app's info.plist and ensure all of the orientations are enabled in the "supported device orientations" section.

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate the OpenGL output in the vertex shader as follows:

```
#version 300 es


in vec4 position;
in mediump vec4 texturecoordinate;

in vec4 color;

uniform float preferredRotation;

out mediump vec2 coordinate;

void main()
{
    //const float pi = 4.0 * atan(1.0);
    //float radians  = (( -90.0 ) / 180.0 * pi );

    // Preferred rotation of video acquired, for example, by:
    // AVAssetTrack *videoTrack = [tracks objectAtIndex:0];
    // CGAffineTransform preferredTransform = [videoTrack preferredTransform];
    // self.glKitView.preferredRotation = -1 * atan2(preferredTransform.b, preferredTransform.a);

    // Preferred rotation for both portrait and landscape           
    mat4 rotationMatrix = mat4( cos(preferredRotation), -sin(preferredRotation), 0.0, 0.0,
                                sin(preferredRotation),  cos(preferredRotation), 0.0, 0.0,
                                0.0,                     0.0,                    1.0, 0.0,
                                0.0,                     0.0,                    0.0, 1.0);

    // Mirror vertical (portrait only)
    mat4 rotationMatrix = mat4( cos(preferredRotation),  sin(preferredRotation), 0.0, 0.0,
                               -sin(preferredRotation),  cos(preferredRotation), 0.0, 0.0,
                                0.0,           0.0,          1.0, 0.0,
                                0.0,           0.0,          0.0, 1.0);

    // Mirror horizontal (landscape only)
    mat4 rotationMatrix = mat4( 1.0, 0.0,                     0.0,                    0.0,
                                0.0, cos(preferredRotation), -sin(preferredRotation), 0.0,
                                0.0, sin(preferredRotation),  cos(preferredRotation), 0.0,
                                0.0, 0.0,                     0.0,                    1.0);

    // Mirror vertical (landscape only)
    mat4 rotationMatrix = mat4( cos(preferredRotation), 0.0, sin(preferredRotation), 0.0,
                                0.0,                    1.0, 0.0,                    0.0,
                               -sin(preferredRotation), 0.0, cos(preferredRotation), 0.0,
                                0.0,                    0.0, 0.0,                    1.0);

    gl_Position = position * rotationMatrix;
    coordinate = texturecoordinate.xy;
}
```

> Obviously, you choose only one matrix4, depending on the orientation
>   of the video, and then its rotation. Each matrix4 flips the video
>   window -- not rotates it. For rotation, you have to first pick the
>   matrix4 based on the orientation, and then substitute the
>   preferredRotation variable with the number of degrees (in radians, the
>   formula for which is also provided).
>
> There are a lot of ways to rotate a view, layer, object, etc.; but, if
>   you're rendering an image via OpenGL, then you should choose this
>   method, and only this method.